# Why is it possible to run files with permissions 600 from Python's subprocess.run()?

Tags: permissions, python, python3

`a.out` is a simple C program that prints "hello world" and has permissions 600:

```
-rw-------  1 jim jim  16K Jan  9 12:23 a.out
```

and so understably, when I try to run it, `./a.out`,
I get `bash: ./a.out: Permission denied`.

Yet when I attempt to run the very same `a.out`
from my Python script the file is executed without asking for
any permissions. My Python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run

run("a.out") 
#run("a.out", shell=True) #this works just as well
```

Why is it so?
Is it a security risk and how might I mitigate it?

P.S. I use Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same `a.out`? You aren't using a full path, so this will run whatever `a.out` is found in the directory where the python script is stored.

Comment: Trying it, python3 will search only for executables in the PATH and not in the current directory (unless the PATH includes . of course). Then choosing an absolute location with a.out mode 0600 of course returns 'Permission denied' either from Python or from shell if the shell option is used. => can't reproduce. You can be yourself convinced of all this by using `strace -f` to run the python program so you'll know where is the a.out that is executed.

Comment: @terdon I've just found out that Python must have been executing `a.out` in another directory than that where the script is stored. That `a.out` had permissions 700.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I will therefore close this as non reproducible. Glad you sorted it out!

Comment: Actually, Python doesn't examine the directory where the script is saved; it simply examines your current working directory (and `run` will also consult directories in your `PATH`). See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)